# having a funtion store a string that it makes lowercase and returns it for later use in C++

Tags: c++, string, function, return-value, tolower

Ok, i have a program I'm trying to make and the basic thing is to keep me from rewriting the same long 4 lines of code over and over throughout the project, I'm wanting to see if i can get it to take a string from cin and make the whole string lowercase (I'm aware of the transform method, but this is so i don't have to write really length if statements) and return that string to be used as a variable in other parts of the program or other functions.

I don't know if I'd just have to make the function's return the variable itself in the main block or what. I'm pretty new to c++ and coding in general, if its possible id like to include spaces, in the string. Again I'm not too experienced in c++ yet so id like to know if its even possible and if so the best way to do it.

here is what i have so far

```
int loAns() {
    string lAnswer; //Makes the lAnswer, a string used for a long answer that a char wouldn't do properly
    cin >> lAnswer; //User enters it
    // using transform() function and ::tolower
    transform(lAnswer.begin(), lAnswer.end(), lAnswer.begin(), ::tolower); //The transform and ::tolower to make it uniform
    cout << lAnswer << endl; //Outputs the lAnswer to console

    return 0; //This is where I'm assuming the variable gets put to be used in the rest of the program
}
```

Comment: Return `lAnswer` instead of `0`  also, change return type of function.

Comment: Recommendation: pass in a reference to the stream, `string loAns(istream & in)` so that you can use this function with files and all other types of streams. Save you from ever having to write this function again. Also worth testing `in >> lAnswer;` to make sure it succeeded. Errors you don't check for sooner or later wind up being bugs you have to hunt.

Answer (score 2):

Your interpretation is correct. Essentially, a function is declared as such:

```
type name ( parameter1, parameter2, ...) 
{
    //statements
    return <var>;
}
```

The `type` is for returning variables back to other programs. In this case, you want to return a `std::string`, so you function could be like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

string loAns()
{
    string lAnswer;
    cin >> lAnswer;
    transform(lAnswer.begin(), lAnswer.end(), lAnswer.begin(), ::tolower);
    return lAnswer;
}

int main()
{
    string s = loAns();
    cout << s;
}
```

Result :

```
xYZabC123
xyzabc123
```

If you wanted spaces in your string, it's possible to use `getline()`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

string loAns()
{
    string lAnswer;
    getline(cin, lAnswer);
    transform(lAnswer.begin(), lAnswer.end(), lAnswer.begin(), ::tolower);
    return lAnswer;
}

int main()
{
    string s = loAns();
    cout << s;
}
```

Result :

```
ABc   XYZ   123&A
abc   xyz   123&a
```

- More info:

Functions : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/functions

`return` : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return

`getline()` : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

- Ran on Code::Blocks 20.03, Windows 10 64-bit
- Also, as @David C. Rankin mentioned below, [`using namespace std;` is not considered a good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696).

Comment: Couple of notes, initialize `std::string lAnswer{};` and whether `std::cin` or `getline()` is used, validate with, e.g. `if (!(std::cin >> lAnswer)) { std::cout << "user canceled input.\n"; return lAnswer; }`. You can simply output the warning and let it fall-through transform without problems as begin and end are the same in that case. References are much better to [C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/). Let's just say some of the advice from the other sites you reference is incomplete at best.

Comment: Also worth mentioning [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/364696)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin yes, I'll modified my answer. Thanks for the comments!